# e.preventDefault not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this and currently have a problem with the code below not working in Firefox.

I am trying to prevent the anchor default by using `e.preventDefault()`. I also tried `return false` instead, but still it appears to still default the anchor position.

Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
    // tabs  
    $('ul.tabNav').each(function(){
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
    $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));
    $links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();    

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: And by "default" you of course mean whatever is in the href attribute, not what's added by a plugin like UI tabs ?

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery. `e.preventDefault()` surely "works". Please provide more information.

Comment: Look to your console for the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would put `e.preventDefault();` first so it's called no matter what.

Without seeing your markup, I can't be sure, but my guess is that `$($(this).attr('href'));` is throwing an error that halts execution and therefore never gets to `e.preventDefault();`.

```
$(this).on('click', 'a', function (e)
{
    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href')); // <-- is probably erroring here.

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();    
});
```

Comment: Wrapping the href attribute in jQuery wouldn't normally cause an error.

Comment: @adeneo: It certainly could. An invalid selector will throw an error.

Comment: @BlueSkies - it's inside an event handler, so how could `$(this)` ever be invalid, and trying to get a href that doesn't exists returns an empty string, so no, not really

Comment: @adeneo: That's not a selector. That's an element. The result of `.attr()` could be an `href` that doesn't parse correctly as a selector.

Comment: @BlueSkies - and as attr() always returns a string, what exactly would that string have to be to cause $() to error out ?

Comment: @adeneo `$("/foo")` would do it.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere, that would be an error, or any string containing $ or € or £ or any other weird character, or starting with "http://" (as in this.href)  etc. and that would be closer to an answer, but there's a rather large possibility the href is something like `#page`, so just assuming the href would cause an error isn't really an answer.

Comment: @adeneo: I'd say it's the most likely candidate. I don't see anything else in the code that has potential for throwing, and OP said that `return false;` also doesn't work, so we know (and could assume anyway) that it has nothing to do with `.preventDefault`.

Comment: @BlueSkies - as there is code for tabs at the top of the question, I'd just rather assume that the issue is that OP is trying to preventDefault on the tab functionality, which of course doesn't work, not even with return false, but as it's just an assumption, I'm not posting it as answer.

Comment: @adeneo: True, that could certainly be the case.

Comment: Whomever downvoted, I think it's time to retract.  I think it's been proven that my answer is definitely a logical possibility and not worthy of a downvote.